# WPF horizontal DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, orientation, wpfdatagrid

I would like to have a WPF DataGrid with a horizontal orientation, does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've done this earlier since we wanted to be able to use the same control for a `DataGrid` and a `PropertyGrid`. Alot of things have to be changed (like alignment, scrolling, positioning of sort-arrows etc.). There is way to much code to post the whole solution but this should get you started. This is an example with Autogenerated TextColumns but you can easily modify it to use other column types.

[image]

```
<ScrollViewer Name="c_dataGridScrollViewer"
              Loaded="c_dataGridScrollViewer_Loaded"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid x:Name="c_dataGrid"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              AutoGeneratedColumns="c_dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And when the Columns are generated, we reverse their positions and rotates the TextBlocks and TextBoxes (This is better than rotating the `DataGridCell` in terms of alignment, blur etc.)

```
private void c_dataGridScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add MouseWheel support for the datagrid scrollviewer.
    c_dataGrid.AddHandler(MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(DataGridMouseWheelHorizontal), true);
}

private void DataGridMouseWheelHorizontal(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MouseWheelEventArgs eargs = (MouseWheelEventArgs)e;
    double x = (double)eargs.Delta;
    double y = c_dataGridScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    c_dataGridScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(y - x);
}

private void c_dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(90));
    foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in c_dataGrid.Columns)
    {
        if (dataGridColumn is DataGridTextColumn)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = dataGridColumn as DataGridTextColumn;

            Style style = new Style(dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle.TargetType, dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle.BasedOn);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 2, 0, 2)));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.LayoutTransformProperty, transformGroup));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));

            Style editingStyle = new Style(dataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle.TargetType, dataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle.BasedOn);
            editingStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 2, 0, 2)));
            editingStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.LayoutTransformProperty, transformGroup));
            editingStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));

            dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle = style;
            dataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle = editingStyle;
        }
    }
    List<DataGridColumn> dataGridColumns = new List<DataGridColumn>();
    foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in c_dataGrid.Columns)
    {
        dataGridColumns.Add(dataGridColumn);
    }
    c_dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridColumns.Reverse();
    foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in dataGridColumns)
    {
        c_dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridColumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works pretty well, the horizontal scrollbar when enabled appears at the top (which is to be expected) and the header resizing behavior is weird (also to be expected) but this is a good starting point for me. Any chance of you posting your entire solution? Would be very much appreciated ;)

Comment: Sorry, I can't. It's built into the solution which is own by my previous company. I can help you on specifics if you post questions but I can't upload the entire solution. Good luck!

Comment: On second thought, some help on getting the horizontal scrollbar below the control would be great

Comment: Updated my example. The parent ScrollViewer handles the scrolling

Comment: See my answer below for important enhancements.

Comment: In case someone has the same problem about the scrollviewer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877314/datagrid-scrolling-will-crop-images-horizontally-instead-of-vertically

Answer (score 22):

I am truly standing on the shoulders of giants here :-) but, I have an additional enhancement.

@dimaKudr suggested a way to transform predefined columns without code behind, and @FrankE refined the order of the columns.  What i am adding is a way to transform, automatically generated columns (`AutoGenerateColumns="True"`), by using the `DataGrid.CellStyle` template.  So the complete (and quite elegant) solution is:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1,0,0,1,0,0"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 13):

I've simplified a little bit previous solution. I do not like black magic with additional scrollviewer, so I do not use it. But instead I use additional scale transformation.

```xml
<DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
    </TransformGroup>
</DataGrid.LayoutTransform>

<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

In case of predefined list of colums it is possible to transfom cells content directly in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="TextCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This allows you completely escape codebehind.

Answer (score 2):

I found this approach very useful, I however did a rotation and a mirroring:

```
TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(90));
transformGroup.Children.Add(new MatrixTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0));
```

or in Xaml:

```
<!-- we rotate the whole DataGrid by -90 degree and then mirror via y-Axis so that it is docked vertically to the left side-->
<DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
        <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1,0,0,1,0,0"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
```

By using the mirroring I have the field at the end of the column list at the bottom instead of at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, great solution, thanks! It also requires modifying row / column selection switch between up/down and left/right buttons. I tried to cover this in the DataGrid's keydown or  keyup events, but that behaves kind of weird, flipping the selection back and forth. Anyone with a better solution than the one below? This is just the code for shift tabbing left and tabbing right through wat are originally the rows.

```
private void c_dataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Tab:
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
            {
                if (c_dataGrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    c_dataGrid.SelectedIndex--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (c_dataGrid.SelectedIndex < c_dataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    c_dataGrid.SelectedIndex++;
                }
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, PreviewKeyDown is the one to intercept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820266/wpf-how-to-handle-keydown-event-for-datagrid