# Possible to switch a data grid from horizontal header to vertical? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF horizontal DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid)

Normally, a data grid has headers at the top and define what is in the columns beneath them. Each row would have information for multiple columns so that you get the nice, normal data view we are all accustomed too.

My question is quite simple: I would like the headers to be the left-most column of my data grid, instead of the top row. I've rotated the entire data grid -90 degrees, but I cannot figure out how to rotate the text that goes inside of the header/columns. It seems like it should be very simple as rotating the entire datagrid was very simple itself.

If I am unclear I apolegize.

Comment: Yes I kept searching for a vertical datagrid, I did not realize I actually needed horizontal!