# WPF - Only specific cells in a DataGridColumn have a CheckBox... Is it ever possible?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox, datagridcolumn, datagridcell

My client asks us to have a form with DataGrid, which is pivoted from the standpoint of how the actual data in a database is.

Below is the (simplified) look of my database.

```
│id|stuff│flag│column│column│column│
------------------------------------
│35| AAA │  0 │ etc. │ blah │ yadda│ 
│58│ BBB │  1 │ etc. │ blah │ yadda│  
│78│ CCC │  0 │ etc. │ blah │ yadda│
```

Below is what I'm asked to create.

```
│HEADER│CODE│DATA1│DATA2│DATA3│
-------------------------------
│ID    | #1 │   35│　 58│　　78│
│STUFF │ #2 │  AAA│  BBB│　CCC│
│FLAG  │ #3 │    0│　　1│　　 0│
│COLUMN│ #4 │ etc.│ etc.│ etc.│
│COLUMN│ #5 │ blah│ blah│ blah│
│COLUMN│ #6 │yadda│yadda│yadda│
```

The flag column is supposed to be either 0 or 1, so I wanted that column to be a  `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, but it's pivoted! Of course, I can (with ease) let the cell only accept 1 or 0 in validation process, yet, I'd still want to know if I could ever make a specified cell in a column have a `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at [this WPF horizontal Datagrid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409402/1466627) taking advantage of `<RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>` to pivot your DataGrid.

---

Below is the copied XAML answer @dimaKudr

```
<DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
    </TransformGroup>
</DataGrid.LayoutTransform>

<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

---

Afterwards, I'd have a look at creating a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and use a `CellTemplate` with a `CheckBox` inside binding to your Flag property, using a Converter to convert the 0 and 1 to true/false

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="FlagColumn" Header="Flag" Width="25" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Flag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource FlagConverter}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Quv What kind of problem?

Comment: I personnaly don't advise the RotateTransform trick to get an "Horizontal" DataGrid. When I tried it, it brought many unsolvable layout issues and I endend up solving the problem differently.

Comment: @Bob. I've posted another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834002/any-equivalent-of-datagridtextcolumn-width-for-datagrid-rows-height. I also have a couple more problems. Much of them can be due to my low skill though, I even struggle with how to restore the border lines that are gone.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible by using [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and adapting the [CellTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) depending on your `DataContext`.