# Rotating DataGridCell will impact the scrollviewer - WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I am working with a inverted DataGrid (columns => rows).
When I'm scrolling down, the elements are cropped horizontally instead of vertically as it is expected. I supposed that the problem is coming from the scrollviewer and it's ContentHorizontalOffset. As it is inverted, it should be vertical.

**What I am getting:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

How can I change that ?

Here some code of what I am doing (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid) and [this](https://rotatedwpfdatagrid.codeplex.com/) ):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyRotatedDataGrid" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="DataGridBase" TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
                </Style >
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: I just found that the responsible of this is setting the DataGridCell. Applying a transform into it will change the scrollviewer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datagrid - Scrolling will crop images horizontally instead of vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877314/datagrid-scrolling-will-crop-images-horizontally-instead-of-vertically)