# Generate a DataGrid from a List using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to create a data grid based on the items of a list of objects.

I have the following class:

```
class BookCopies
{
    private string bookTitle;

    private int bookNumbers;

    public string BookTitle
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public int BookNumbers
    {
        get;

        set;
    }
}
```

and then i populate a classical list with items of this type

```
List<BookCopies> booksWithCopies = new List<BookCopies>();

//...

return booksWithCopies;
```

Basically this list will contain items like ("The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", 3) , ("Infinite Jest" , 8) and so on... It keeps a book title and the number of books from the bookstore.

I know that this list has to be converted to a ObservableCollection and raise the NotifyPropertyChanged in order to have the mvvm pattern as it should.

Now what I am trying is to use this book list to set the content of the grid view. So the book title to become the column header and below it to have the number of books. Basically the grid to look something like this:

[image: Grid layout]

Most of the examples where hard coding the header of the column, now I am trying to read it from a list, and also to bound the content of the grid from the same list.

I am quite new to WPF and also MVVM and first I am thinking if this is possible (it will be nice to... since I have all the data that I need already in a list) and if that is possible to send me some examples or quide me through a little bit about how to implement this.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was checking it... It is nicely solving the UI presentation of elements but it seems that is not fetching the data from any list.

Comment: have you set `ItemsSource` for your `DataGrid`, plz check my updated answer, I have added output Image.

Comment: ` List<BookCopies> copies = new List<BookCopies>() 
            {  new BookCopies() { BookTitle = "Book1", BookNumbers = 2 }, 
                new BookCopies() { BookTitle = "Book2 for u", BookNumbers = 4 },
                new BookCopies() { BookTitle = "Let us C", BookNumbers = 3 }};

            Dgrd.ItemsSource = copies;`

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd" HeadersVisibility="Row" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LawnGreen" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkViolet"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
                        <StackPanel>
                                <Label Padding="5" Content="{Binding BookTitle}" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="DarkViolet" Background="Transparent"/>
                                <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="{Binding BookNumbers}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DataGridRowsPresenter  Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: Output for horizontal grid]

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve what you are trying to because DataGrid does not work that way. The bounded collection on the DataGrid (itemsource) is used to populate the row of the DataGrid.

However there are others trying to do the same thing you are. Take a look on [WPF horizontal DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid), the result is similar to what you are describing (except the column names on the left). The resulting solution requires some coding.

Another resource you can look into is the [Displaying vertical rows in a DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5030/Displaying-vertical-rows-in-a-DataGrid) from Code Project website.